# Союз "а" и частица "же"

Tags: синтаксис, союзы, частицы

Во всех ли случаях конструкцию с союзом "а" можно заменить конструкцией с частицей "же" ("Вчера было так, а сегодня всё иначе" = "Вчера было так, сегодня же всё иначе")? Или в каких-то случаях нельзя?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > Во всех ли случаях конструкцию с союзом "а" можно заменить конструкцией с частицей "же"  ("Вчера было так, а сегодня всё иначе" = "Вчера было так, сегодня же всё иначе")?

Здесь ЖЕ не частица, а тоже союз.

*Это был Вася Петров, а не Петя Васечкин.* Здесь на ЖЕ не заменить.